# objective-c add image to UINavigationBar programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to add a pause button to the right side of my navigation bar but I can't get the icon to display.  Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  //create the navigation bar
  UINavigationBar *navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 30)];
  [self.view addSubview:navbar];

  //add the image to the navigation bar
  UIImageView *tileImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"glyphicons_174_pause.png"]];
  tileImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 25);
  self.navigationItem.titleView = tileImageView;
}
```

I've tried many different things here and nothing seems to work.  My image is located in the root directory of the project along with all my classes for simplicity and to ensure it's not a relative path issue.  I know I'm using `titleView` here but I just want it to display; after that I'll figure out how to position it (probably by using `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` *wink* *wink*)

Anyway, any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

**EDIT**

Ultimately, I think I'd rather do it this way if possible:

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"glyphicons_174_pause.png"]]];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

But this isn't working either; the image doesn't get displayed at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your View Controller is inside of Navigation Controller hierarchy then only

> self.navigationItem.titleView = tileImageView;

will work.

Otherwise you have to add custom view as titleview or barbutton items to NavigationBar

```
UINavigationBar *navbar = [[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width, 30)];    [self.view addSubview:navbar]; 

UIImageView *tileImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"glyphicons_174_pause.png"]];
tileImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 25);    
[navbar addSubView:tileImageView];
```

Regards.

Comment: This seems to work the best, how can I add an action to it to call another method when clicked?

Comment: You can add UIButton same way like UIImageView and using UIButton TouchUpInside delegate method you can have any code.

Comment: would it be possible for you to show an example in your post above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"glyphicons_174_pause.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:img1 
                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                 target:self action:@selector(onBtnClicked:)];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn;
```

Comment: Your's still results in the image not being displayed

Answer (score 0):

As far as `UINavigationBar` is concerned, try this :

```
[myNavbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"glyphicons_174_pause.png"] 
               forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Yours displays the image but it tiles it repeating horizontally.  I would ultimately like the image to be aligned to the right side of the navbar and not repeating